# Problem Of Hudson using GitHub Repositories

Tags: git, ssh, hudson, window, service

I am using Hudson in windows which takes the data from the GitHub Repository but is unable to clone the data because of SSH Key given in GitHub.How to provide the information of SSH in hudson so that it can access the GitHub Repository.
Thnx in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to provide an SSH key to clone a Github repo. It can be read-only cloned using either:
`https://github.com/user/reponame.git` or
`git://github.com/user/reponame.git`

Comment: Thanks you are such a saviour.

Comment: I am facing another problem...I am facing a problem regarding Hudson and NUnit testing.Actually Everything is working fine.Even the NUnit Testing is also working but my problem arise on publishing the Test Result Report for NUnit.The Option in Hudson i.e."Publish NUnit Test Result Reports " is creating a problem.I am unable to provide the Path of the XML file which is already created under workspace folder of the Job.When I set the path of the my file i.e."nunit-result.xml" and run the job it throws an error "No test report files were found. Configuration error?".Please Help